# Master Page Error on New MVC Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've just create a new MVC project, and have made no changes at all, but when I try and view the ChangePasswordSuccess view in design mode, I get the error:

```
The page has controls that require a Master Page reference, but none is supplied.
```

The page has no controls except for a content control and literal text, and it does have a master page reference.  Anyone know what's up?

```
<%@Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ChangePasswordSuccess.aspx.cs" Inherits="BasicMvcApp.Views.Account.ChangePasswordSuccess" %>

<asp:Content ID="changePasswordSuccessContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>Change Password</h2>
    <p>
        Your password has been changed successfully.
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No sooner asked than noticed.  The default ChangePasswordSuccess view's Page directive is missing the word `Page`.