# 'The page has controls that require a Master Page reference, but none is specified' issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, master-pages

I'm getting this output:[image]

even though my page contains `MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master"`

Here's my page's source code:

```
<%@ Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Projekt.NET.WebForm2" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<title>gowno</title>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
hahahahahahaa
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 2):

as Self-Anserwed by 'ProfK'

`<%@ Page Language="C#"` *'directive is missing the word Page'*

[Master Page Error on New MVC Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333393/master-page-error-on-new-mvc-project)